# Closure compiler - wrongly obfuscates class members

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler

Im using closure compiler in advanced optimization mode to obfuscate javascript.
I have few doubts regarding the obfuscation of class member variables.
Here is a snippet of JS im trying to obfuscate.

```
function MyClass(){
   this.someFlag = false;
}
MyClass.prototype.myClassMethod = function (){
   if(this.someFlag) {
     console.log("Flag is true"); 
   }
}
```

I see inconsistent behaviour in obfuscation of class member variables by closure compiler.
I have clearly described the inconsistency via the following 2 cases.
Case 1: (Class member variable "someFlag" correctly obfuscated)

```
function a(){
  this.c = 0;
}
a.prototype.b = function(){
  if(this.c){
    console.log("Flag is true");
   }
}
```

Case 2: (Class member variable "someFlag" incorrectly obfuscated)

```
function a(){
  this.c = 0;//here someflag is obfuscated as c
}
a.prototype.b = function(){
  if(this.d){ //here someFlag is obfuscated as d
    console.log("Flag is true");
   }
}
```

Its not the same snippet of code that gets inconsistently obfuscated when running closure compiler on it. But similar pattern of Javascript code gets obfuscated in inconsistent manner.
The current solution im using to prevent this inconsistency is to use quoted syntax for the impacted class variable. Like this: `this["someFlag"]`
But using quoted syntax prevent obfuscating the class variable "someFlag". I want to obfuscate the class variables too.
I want to know why closure compiler gets confused with class variables and incorrectly obfuscates in somecases ? Is using quoted syntax the only solution to avoid this inconsistency ? Is there anyother solution ?

Comment: Are you referring to the same variable? Can you post the second snippet?

Comment: "*Its not the same snippet of code […] but [a] similar pattern*" - can you please post a minimal example that lets us reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Bergi What I was trying to say is that, class member variable in one of the class gets correctly obfuscated, whereas member variable in another class gets incorrectly obfuscated. Both classes have structure similar to the example I already posted.

Comment: @sagi . The class which has the incorrect obfuscation issue is exactly similar to the example I posted in the question

Comment: Lying to the type system can produce results like this. If you can't post a reproducible sample, then I recommend disabling the type based optimizations: `--use_types_for_optimization=false`

Comment: @chad Can you eloborate on what you mean by "lying to the type system can produce results like this " ?

Comment: You lie to the type system when you use incorrect type annotations. It's surprisingly easy to do. I'm on my phone so I can't post a full example.

Comment: @Chad Im not using  type annotation in my script. So I dont think what you mentioned is the rootcause for the problem